# How do I fix my array formula in google sheets so the formula automatically populates when I add new row

Tags: google-sheets

My formula in Z49 is: =arrayformula(if(row(A49:A)=49,"Combined",if(isblank(A49:A),"",sum($V50:$Y50))))

My calculation in Z55 & Z56 is incorrect (I desire the sum of V55:Y55, respectively)

[Worksheet for Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp9EN.jpg)

My formula in Z49 is: =arrayformula(if(row(A49:A)=49,"Combined",if(isblank(A49:A),"",sum($V50:$Y50))))

My calculation in Z55 & Z56 is incorrect (I desire the sum of V55:Y55, respectively)

Answer (score 0):

Another similar option, more similar to yours:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A49:A),"", BYROW(V49:Y,LAMBDA(r,SUM(r)))))
```

Or, just using the original but replacing SUM:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A49:A),"",V49:V+A49:W+X49:X+Y49:Y))
```

Answer (score -1):

*You could try this in `Cell_Z49`:*

```js
=vstack("combined",
         byrow(V50:Y,lambda(Σ,if(offset(index(Σ,,1),,-21)="",,sum(Σ)))))
```

Comment: Well, that worked indeed.....but I need to understand how that worked and particularly what is the purpose of "-21"? so that I can duplicate that again.

Comment: this `byrow` [video](https://youtu.be/JYRMZ00WjgQ?t=616) and/or [article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/byrow-function/) should be helpful. `offset(index(Σ,,1),,-21)=""` is kinda equal to `isblank(A50:A)` in your original formula. In other words I am just pointing it to Column_A to check if its blank or aint and Column_A is 21 columns behind of Column_V per se.,